# android - error onListItemClick , The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment

i have error in my project please help me, this my code

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}
```

error find in onListItemClick, error message "The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type Fragment" i can fix it ... thanks, please help me

Comment: Is your fragment a `ListFragment` type?

Comment: @zozelfelfo Just Fragment ...

Comment: There you have it then :)

Comment: and than, what should i do? @zozelfelfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Change your class `Fragment` for `ListFragment`
2. Make sure that your `ListFragment` has the following id `@android:id/list`.
3. Put `@Override` in your method

Hope it helps

Comment: i try it, but i change Fragment to ListFragment have many error in my code, why @zozelfelfo

Comment: this my full code @zozelfelfo, please help [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723215/error-onlistitemclick-and-setlistadapter-is-undefined-for-the-type-fragment

Comment: Thanks @zozelfelfo for help, its all been clear, but now i have any problem, in my Sliding menu, i can't click Review Menu, this my full code [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723596/i-cant-click-listview-in-slidingmenu-fragment-layout-doesnt-appear , maybe you can help again, thanks before

Comment: If this helped you please mark the answer as correct :), I'll check your other question