# I can't click ListView in SlidingMenu Fragment, Layout doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, slidingmenu

why i can klik listview (ReviewFragment) and its layout does not appear, i have SlidingMenu, when i click my Review menu layout does not appear, please have, maybe in my code i have mistake,

### this my ReviewFragment.java :

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;


import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ReviewFragment extends ListFragment {

private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private int mNoteNumber = 1;

private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_review, container, false);

    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter (getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();

    registerForContextMenu(getView());
    Button addnote = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addnotebutton);
    addnote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createNote();
            }
    });return v; 
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater mInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    mInflater.inflate(R.menu.notelist_menu, menu);

}

private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);     
}


public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE ,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DATE};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 ,R.id.date_row};

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.note_row, notesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();

}  
}
```

### And this my SlidingMenu, MainActivity.java code

```
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        ListFragment listfragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            listfragment = new ReviewFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Thanks before, help me because it was nearing the deadline for campus

Comment: sorry I don't understand what exactly is not working here? What's supposed to happen?

Comment: so here @user3249477 , MainActivity.java is my sliding menu code, and than ReviewFragment.java is one of menu in the sliding menu title "Create review", but when I click it, it does't appear, whether there are errors in both my code? this picture my sliding menu [link]https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByG6SQwo5vbwWG0wWmVOazhCbzQ/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Don't change this, as I suggested earlier:

```
case 3:
            listfragment = new ReviewFragment();
            break;
```

**Only** change the code after switch to this:

```
if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
} else if (listfragment != null) {
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.frame_container, listfragment).commit();
} else {
    // error in creating fragment
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
}
```

Comment: i try it @user3249477 but error massage now "fragmentlist cannot be resolved to a variable" , what should i do??

Comment: @RuhbiAnugrahP please use the last piece of code. The first one i added is probably not what you want. I updated the code, mispelled your variable's name.

Comment: after change listfragment to fragment, this message is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ReviewFragment to Fragment" , what should i do again @user3249477?

Comment: @RuhbiAnugrahP Sorry I didn't notice your fragments are of different type. Updated the answer.

Comment: this my update question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724940/android-error-the-method-replaceint-fragment-in-the-type-fragmenttransactio

Comment: @RuhbiAnugrahP if my answer helped you, then select it as correct instead of creating new questions.